# Deep in FFT, FFT based on magnititude-frequency characteristic

Tags: signal-processing, fft

Given a baseband signal and I get the magnititude-frequency characteristic by FFT, then I utilize FFT again based on the magnititude-frequency characteristic, what is the meaning of that result? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

The magnitude-only result of throws away phase information. So the waveform of either an FFT(abs(FFT())) or IFFT(abs(FFT())) will likely be distorted, and possibly be changed to something that looks partially or more like the Hilbert transform of the original waveform.

If the forward FFT implementation has a scale factor of N or 1/N, then the waveform amplitude of an FFT(FFT()) will be changed.  But if the FFT implementation has a scale factor of 1/sqrt(N), then not.

If a strictly real waveform is not so distorted by scale or phase as to be unrecognizable, then the waveform of an FFT(FFT()) will be reversed in time (compared to an IFFT(FFT(x) which does not time reverse x).